# How to change 4 sides grid view to display corner radius?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, gridview

I work on `asp.net web forms` . I face issue i can't change header of grid view to take corner radius on 4 sides .

so I need to get header style and give it as CSS style or bootstrap to grid view to be get corner side radius on 4 sides
top left - top right -bottom left-bottom right

exactly I need to get same corner on every side

grid view component as below :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSearchData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#172b4d"   AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdData_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="10">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select All" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <asp:BoundField DataField="BranchCode" HeaderText="BranchCode" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderNo" HeaderText="OrderNo" ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderType" HeaderText="OrderType" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Printer_name" HeaderText="Printer_name" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="EntredDatetime" HeaderText="EntredDatetime" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  />                            
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden"  />
       
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

expected result as below :
[image: same corner radius on 4 sides]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by this steps :

1- I add CSS class as below :

```css
.corners {
  border: 0px solid blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}
```

2- Add div contain grid view

3- Assign class to div contain grid view by CSS as below :

```html
<div class="corners">
  <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSearchData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table"  HeaderStyle-BackColor="#172b4d" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"   AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdData_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="10" >                           
  </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And it is working.